# new server/website appears to be caching but cache is turned off

Tags: caching, windows-7, iis-7.5

I recently setup a home server running windows 7 pro and IIS 7.5. I have an ASP page that reads/writes to a database. One scenario I have is a newsletter with a list of subscribers. I manually check a box next to a user's name and they get added to a table that associates that userid with a messageid.

When the page loads initially, let's say I've previously added a user to the newsletter. I have a variable that displays that says "1 subscriber". If I add a user (by checking a box next to their name, hitting submit and submitting a form to the same page but with an action=submit added) the user entry will be added to the DB, the script file then redirects to the same page without the action=submit and Session("msg") will show as "updated successfully" but the subscriber count will equal 1 still. If I hit F5, the number updates.

Everything I've read along with what knowledge I have of programming points to it being a caching issue. However, I've taken all the steps I can find online to disable all caching.

Is there something I might be missing or might it not be a caching issue at all but rather something else? I've used this style of programming for years on other servers without any issues which is why I feel like it points to a setting somewhere.

This is the first server, I've been the admin for so I'm kinda bumbling my way through these things as they come up.

---

subscribers.asp?cid=5

- polls DB to pull count of number of subscribers (audience)

  - [subscribers show 1]
- polls DB to pull all email addresses in DB (subscribers)

  - list available email address within form

I check appropriate checkboxes next to name(s) and submit form

- form submits to subscribers.asp?cid=5 with hidden input type name=action value=submit

Script runs (if action=submit then)

- insert subscriber ids into audience table
- set RS and Conn = Nothing
- response.redirect(subscribers.asp?cid=5)

GOTO TOP

subscribers still show as 1. Hit F5, now it shows incremented appropriately.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are your browser cache settings?

Comment: I have followed instructions I was able to find online to turn if off in both FF and IE.

Comment: is the submit and message response being done by ajax without a full page reload?

Comment: Nope, it's a full page reload for both the form submit and then the Redirect

Comment: hmm, running  out of ideas here... Is it possible the db insert of the new value takes a second and the 'new' read is getting the old value?

Comment: Actually it looks exactly like that is happening. I was just going to post that if I add a delay of 1 second before redirecting it works for the most part. If I add a 2 second delay before redirecting it works fine. Do you know if there is a way around this somehow without having to manually add a delay?

Comment: sorry I just dont know.